# CSS Equal Height columns issue in Chrome not Safari

Tags: css, height, gradient, equals

I'm using linear gradients to create equal height columns. In safari everything lines up and is fluid all the way from desktop to mobile.

My setup is 2 rows each containing 2 columns each column has an image and a description box underneath. The image is responsive so scales down in size but in Safari this isn't an issue everything continues to line up i.e. the edge of the gradient column (the line where the two colours meet) is in line with the image at every break point.

However in Chrome nothing lines up when you scale down. It's fine at desktop but as soon as you view smaller screen sizes the images and the line dividing the two columns are all off. 
I have searched endlessly for a solution to this problem but cant's seem to find anything.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<article class="rowContainer">
  <div class="rowOne">
 <section class="floatLeft textLightGreyArea">
   <img src="..." />
   <p>Description goes here</p>
 </section>

 <section class="floatLeft textDarkGreyArea">
   <p>Description goes here</p>
   <img src="..." />
 </section>
 </div>
 </article>


 <article class="rowContainer">
   <div class="rowTwo">
 <section class="floatLeft textLightGreyArea">
   <img src="..." />
   <p>Description goes here</p>
 </section>

 <section class="floatLeft textDarkGreyArea">
   <img src="..." />
   <p>Description goes here</p>
 </section>
 </div>
 </article>
```

CSS

```
 .rowContainer:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 }

 .rowContainer {
 display: inline-block;
 }

.rowOne {
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #c9c9c9;
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #c9c9c9),  
   color-stop(49.99%, #c9c9c9), color-stop(49.99%, #e0e0e0), color-stop(100%, #e0e0e0));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #c9c9c9, #c9c9c9 49.99%, #e0e0e0 
   49.99%, 
   #e0e0e0 100%);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #c9c9c9, #c9c9c9 49.99%, #e0e0e0 49.99%,    
   #e0e0e0 100%);
   }

   .rowTwo {
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #e0e0e0;
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #e0e0e0),   
   color-stop(49.99%, #e0e0e0), color-stop(49.99%, #c9c9c9), color-stop(100%, #c9c9c9));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e0e0e0, #e0e0e0 49.99%, #c9c9c9 
   49.99%,    
   #c9c9c9 100%);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #e0e0e0, #e0e0e0 49.99%, #c9c9c9 49.99%, 
   #c9c9c9 100%);
   }

   .floatLeft {
   width: 49.99%;
   float: left;
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ht25w/1/

Comment: provide a link ya code

Comment: I've just updated with the code - I wanted to upload an image but i don't think i can

Comment: Can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: ok I'll have a go one sec

Comment: Here is the setup - although i notice there is a gap at the bottom of the right image http://jsfiddle.net/Ht25w/1/ - can you see in chrome this is a slight gap rather than it being flush, In my site as it is on a larger scale its really obvious and ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a bug with chrome and gradients, it's obviously not your fault. the simplest solution is to give the background gradient to each  instead on the father

a solution to fix text in each box is to use display table / table cell with 50% width, give half gradient to each and bottom align the right box while positioning the text absolute to top like in this [http://jsfiddle.net/Ht25w/8/]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. I already have a max-width: 100% on the images and just tried max-height:100% and max-height:auto and that didn't fix it.

Comment: make that fiddle, it'll take one second to see what's wrong there :)

Comment: ok there is a bug with chrome and gradients, it's obviously not your fault.
the simplest solution is to give the background gradient to each <section> instead on the father <div>, try giving them the same gradient split in half.

Comment: Could you explain this further? Will applying the gradient to the section not cause problems with the equal height columns? Thanks for taking the time to look by the way.

Comment: voilà http://jsfiddle.net/Ht25w/4/
used display table / table-cell for box heights and splitted the gradient (remember to remove the floats and add other gradient support)

Comment: Thanks for sending that over but doing it that way doesn't achieve what I was looking for. The two boxes of text need to expand to equal height so that both columns line up like in the previous jsfiddle no matter how much content is in the box. Basically the right hand image needs to be at the bottom of that container. I'm also using gridset to prefix my site I don't know if this will affect this method also?

Comment: Is there a way to get the image to position at the bottom of that container?

Comment: of course, there are many ways that depends on how text evolve. 

first way: 
.textDarkGreyArea{ position: relative; } 
.textDarkGreyArea { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; }

second way: 
.textDarkGreyArea p{ height: 80%; }
.textDarkGreyArea img { height: 20%; }

third way: 
.textDarkGreyArea { position: relative; vertical-align: bottom; }
.textDarkGreyArea p{ position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }

and there are other of course

Comment: First way didn't work, second way - the text put into this field may vary as its linked to a CMS so I don't want to define the height by 80% this also pushes the image outside of the container. Just tried the third way and that seems to work. If you update your answer to the one you put in your comment I can accept it. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: After trying the third method for positioning the image at the bottom, it didn't seem to work. I don't suppose you have other options to suggest I can't work it out.